# Why preg_replace return null?

Tags: php, regex, url, get, preg-replace

I have next code:
[CODE from debug](http://joxi.ru/Drl77BgUBV60AP)

or :

```
$pattern="/?page=1/";
$url="/en/catalog/blouses.htm?page=1";
$temp = preg_replace ( $pattern, "" , $url);

//return null
```

But with:

```
$pattern ="/&page=1/";
```

all is ok

Answer (score 4):

Escape the `?` . Because `?` is a special char in regex (*acts like an optional quantifier or non-greedy quantifier*) . You need to escape that in-order to match a literal `?` character.

```
$pattern='/\?page=1/';
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/dbYMl)

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern="/[&\?]page=1/";
```

See here `&` OR `?`

in your code searching for `&` which is not present.

```
$url="/en/catalog/blouses.htm?page=1";
$temp = preg_replace ( $pattern, "" , $url);
echo $temp;
```